# create a shell script to install updates

Tags: scripting

OK based on some additional research and the yum answer below, this is what i would like my script to do:

1. extract the updates
2. install the updates in a specific order
3. wait a few seconds for the yum update to finish for each section
4. reset the root account password (how do i hardcode or set that via the script?)
5. reset the ssh account password (how do i hardcode or set that via the script?)
6. clear the history
7. remove the files
8. prompt for a reboot

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   # Run as root

   # This extracts the tar copied to the server
   tar -xf updates
   sleep 5
   tar -xf app
   sleep 2

   # This moves to the February updates and install it.
   cd /updates/feb
   yum -y update *.rpm
   sleep 5
   # This moves to the March updates and install it.
   cd /updates/mar
   yum -y update *.rpm
   sleep 5
   # This moves to the April updates and install it.
   cd /updates/apr
   yum -y update *.rpm
   sleep 5
   # This moves to the May updates and install it.
   cd /updates/may
   yum -y update *.rpm
   sleep 5
   # This moves to the June updates and install it.
   cd /updates/june
   yum -y update *.rpm
   sleep 5
   # This moves to the August updates and install it.
   cd /updates/aug
   yum -y update *.rpm
   sleep 5
   # This moves to the September updates and install it.
   cd /updates/sep
   yum -y update *.rpm
   sleep 5
   # This moves to the APP dependencies and install it.
   cd /updates/app
   yum -y install *.rpm
   sleep 5
   # This resets the root password
   passwd root
   # This resets the ssh account password
   passwd ssh_user
   # This removes the files from the home directory
   cd /home/user
   rm -rf /updates
   wait 5
   # This clears the history and screen
   history -c
   clear
   # This reboots the server with a y/n prompt
   reboot
   ```

EDITED for updates and to apologize for being a noob!

Answer (score 2):

Add `-y` (tells yum to assume "yes" answers) like this:

```
yum -y update *.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks CharlesB Good call. ;)